# Android Firebase how to retrieve one record by ID?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's some of my Firebase data

```
my_first_app
  my_msg
    -KjX-kovDZiCB5yuiwt6:"test msg1"
    -KjX-yZWKfkhZmAqzHRQ:"test msg2"
```

In my Android app how do I retrieve the value "test msg2" by using the ID of -KjX-yZWKfkhZmAqzHRQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you as long as your Firebase database rules allow read access on "my_msg/-KjX-yZWKfkhZmAqzHRQ" path.

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("my_msg/-KjX-yZWKfkhZmAqzHRQ");
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        // value now contains "test msg2"
        //TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        //tv.setText(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

If you only need to access retrieve the value of "test msg 2" once instead of listen for changes, you can use `myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` instead of `myRef.addValueEventListener()` as [stated here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once).

Comment: In your code, you actually only need read access on `my_msg/-KjX-yZWKfkhZmAqzHRQ`.